# On hold after accepted answer... what is the point?

Tags: discussion

This situation is definitely not unique, but the case I am referring to is here: [To dis assemble a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50210949/to-dis-assemble-a-string)

1. A poorly worded question is posted.
2. Clarifications are sought, in the comments of the question.
3. One or more cut-and-paste answers are provided, based on the answerer's understanding of the question.
4. The people who still believe in a high level of quality for SO are awaiting further clarity in the question, before attempting to answer.
5. The OP accepts one of the cut-and-paste answers.
6. The question is put on hold for being unclear.

Isn't all this just a waste of time?

The OP has been given an answer to an unclear question. The answerer has been given reputation points, simply for being fast enough with an answer. The question is on hold, and it is unlikely that the OP will ever return to fix anything about the question, because they have what they wanted. And, the end result is that we have yet another poorly formulated question - answer pair, which does wonders for the site's image of being a quality resource.

I am not sure what the solution is, but there is clearly a disconnect between the members who are only interested in reputation points (cf the answerer above) and the members who are interested in maintaining quality (cf the members who put the question on hold).

Comment: @gnat The question referred to is asking about the possibility of closing a question with an accepted answer. I don't care if it is possible, I am just asking if it makes sense to put a question on hold when it is obviously flawed.

Comment: In cases like this, closing might be a preliminary step towards [deletion via votes by 10k+ users](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/242059).

Comment: While we can argue whether this is an exact duplicate, until the cows come home, I think that sub-standard questions should be given a chance to redeem themselves, and then they should be closed / deleted / whatever - regardless of whether there is an accepted answer or not.

Comment: Question closing is a signal that there's something wrong with the question.  It can still be edited while on-hold or closed.  If it doesn't, though, it will eventually be deleted (unless it's a duplicate).

Comment: Note that the motivations are not always rep vs. quality. I've seen people with hundreds of thousands of rep answering obvious duplicates because "it's easier to answer than it is to find a duplicate", or "just wanted to help the user out". IMHO, that's being almost as selfish as if it were for rep, because it lowers the overall quality of the site, but that's a different topic.